# facebook check user allow install my app or not

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

I know this query is check people liked my page or not.

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
```

However, I want to know people allowed / installed my app or not.
Does Someone help me the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask for the permissions of the logged in user, the path is *[/me/permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/permissions)*, if the user has allowed your app then you'll get something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

(and more permissions the user granted the app)

If the app was not allowed you'll probably get this kind of exception:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: User USER_ID has not authorized application 145634995501895.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 190
  }
}
```

or just *"installed": 0*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with FQL it is similar to the following
(this assumes you're checking the logged in user)

```
 fql?q=SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user where uid = me()
```

is_app_user will return either true or false. If you want to add it into the WHERE clause as well the "true" or "false" needs to be in quotes

e.g

```
 fql?q=SELECT uid, name,is_app_user FROM user where uid = me() and is_app_user='true'
```